# Calculate mean difference with covariate between groups of different sample size

Tags: r, covariance, comparison-operators, p-value

I need to calculate the p-value indicating the difference of score values between groups taking the 'Age' variable as a covariate- How should I calculate and present it given that each groups has a different sample size?

```
data<-structure(list(Subject = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
14, 27, 28, 1, 2, 18, 19, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 15, 16, 17, 20, 
21), Group = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Age = c(60.9, 60.9, 61.5, 
61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 61.5, 62.7, 62.7, 63.5, 63.5, 61.8, 61.8, 
63.6, 63.6, 62.9, 62.9, 63.2, 63.2, 64.1, 60.4, 60.4, 62.9, 63.1, 
63.1, 61.2, 61.2), Score = c(103, 92, 85, 84, 124, 120, 85, 87, 
77, 83, 85, 75, 91, 90, 140, 99, 101, 101, 97, 100, 114, 105, 
99, 101, 82, 92, 84, 89)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(14L, 
19L, 71L, 72L, 97L, 100L, 117L, 121L, 124L, 127L, 135L, 137L, 
194L, 195L, 246L, 247L, 297L, 300L, 330L, 331L, 362L, 364L, 366L, 
440L, 442L, 443L, 504L, 507L))
```

Would the correlation of each group score and age, then comparison of P, R suffice?

Answer (score 1):

You could run a multiple regression and use robust standard errors:

```
data$Group <- factor(data$Group)
m <- lm(Score ~ Group * Age, data = data)
library(lmtest)
library(sandwich)
coeftest(m, vcov = vcovHC(m, type="HC1"))

t test of coefficients:

             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) -56.17586  178.51065 -0.3147  0.75596  
Group2      685.13412  255.34576  2.6832  0.01358 *
Group3      -26.46759  236.94890 -0.1117  0.91207  
Age           2.33990    2.90589  0.8052  0.42931  
Group2:Age  -11.02058    4.11310 -2.6794  0.01370 *
Group3:Age    0.67231    3.86276  0.1740  0.86342  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

And maybe include a plot so that one can see that the groups are not of the same size:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Age, y = Score)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~Group, labeller = as_labeller(c("1" = "group 1", "2" = "group 2", "3" = "group 3")))
```

[image]

---

Centered data:

```
data <- data %>% 
  mutate(Age_centered = scale(Age, center = TRUE))

m <- lm(Score ~ Group * Age_centered, data = data)
coeftest(m, vcov = vcovHC(m, type="HC1"))

t test of coefficients:

                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)          89.44958    3.06921 29.1441  < 2e-16 ***
Group2               -0.73980    4.39059 -0.1685  0.86773    
Group3               15.37412    4.81025  3.1961  0.00417 ** 
Age_centered          2.53076    3.14291  0.8052  0.42931    
Group2:Age_centered -11.91951    4.44860 -2.6794  0.01370 *  
Group3:Age_centered   0.72715    4.17783  0.1740  0.86342    

data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Age_centered, y = Score, color = Group)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. To make sure I interpret correctly- In this case, would it be right to say that by considering age as covariate (the age relationship), compared to Group 1, Group 2 has significantly lower values (p=0.013) while group 3 doesn't (p=0.863)?

Comment: It means that at an Age value of 0 (the intercept), group 2 has a significantly higher Score value than group 1, while group 3 doesn't. To compare the means if would center the data (see edit). Then you see that Group 3 has on average significantly higher values at the overall mean of Age compared to group 1.